# How to Reshape random pandas columns so that they can be broadcasted?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, reshape, shapes

So I am making a trading algorithm that is using an SMA crossover. The code is as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
import pandas_datareader as data
import datetime as dt
import numpy as np

start = dt.datetime(2018, 1, 1)
end = dt.datetime(2020, 4, 20)
d = data.get_data_yahoo('URI', start, end)


d['sma50'] = np.round(d['Close'].rolling(window=2).mean(), decimals=2)
d['sma200'] = np.round(d['Close'].rolling(window=14).mean(), decimals=2)
d['200-50'] = d['sma200'] - d['sma50']
_buy = -2
d['Crossover_Long'] = np.where(d['200-50'] < _buy, 1, 0)
d['Crossover_Long_Change']=d.Crossover_Long.diff()
d['buy'] = np.where(d['Crossover_Long_Change'] == 1, 'buy', 'n/a')
#there has to be sell paramters such as if the 200-50 becomes to wide 
d['sell'] = np.where(d['Crossover_Long_Change'] == -1, 'sell', 'n/a')
pd.set_option('display.max_rows', 5093)
d.drop(['High', 'Low', 'Close', 'Volume', 'Open'], axis=1, inplace=True)
d.dropna(inplace=True)
d

d.set_index(d['Adj Close'], inplace=True)
buy_price = d.index[d['Crossover_Long_Change']==1]
sell_price = d.index[d['Crossover_Long_Change']==-1]
profit_loss = sell_price - buy_price
```

If the crossover that is a buy signal occurs then it prints a 1, if a crossover that is a sell signal ocurs then it will print a -1. Then I set the index as the ADJ close price so that I could index out the prices of when this happened to create another data frame. For example I indexed out the price for a company such as URI, there are 26 sell orders and 26 buy orders.
We can see this by doing:

```
d['Crossover_Long_Change'].value_counts()
```

Which prints:

```
 0.0    513
-1.0     26
 1.0     26
Name: Crossover_Long_Change, dtype: int64
```

But if I were to use a company such as AMD, then there would be 21 buy orders and 20 sell orders. Therefore when I broadcast them to find the Profit_loss I recive the error:

```
alueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (20,) (21,)
```

So what would be a way to always ensure that the shape was correct to do operations on them ? Thank you.

(SIDE NOTE: I was thinking of using reshape, but then would that ruin the trading but forcing it to add another -1 which means it would sell when the time ends not when the crossover occurs?, thank you again)

Comment: What shape would be correct?  20?  21?  (20,21)? or something else?

Comment: It would be 21 and 21. But even if I were to reshape to 21, 21 then it would only be good for AMD not for any other company if I were to change the ticker